# How to calculate a missing md5 for a file in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, storage, md5

A couple of other discussions exist with a similar-ish issue to solve, but no solution was found in them, so I try my luck too:

Files in Azure blob storage do not always have an md5 value stored in the settings. If that happens, the generally known solution after-the-fact (when such a file already exists in Azure blob storage) is to download the file, optionally calculate the md5 in your local system, but in any case upload the file back to Azure blob storage, this time using settings that (hopefully) cause the md5 value to be stored by Azure.

This is not very effective, however. The most effective action would be that Azure calculates the missing md5 value for a file in blob storage, and at least tells it to me, and in the best case saves it in the file settings. Is it possible to get this done, with some reasonable efficiency, or is the only possible way to decipher the missing md5 value to download the file, and then calculate the md5 locally?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Azure Event Grid / Azure Functions and check if there is the md5 otherwise would calculate and update it.

As far as I know, there's no way to trigger/filter only the blobs without md5, so this 'solution' will run over all your files. Take this in consideration as I don't know how many files we're talking about.

Comment: I have a way of reading the md5 values, so I am able to know, which of them have the value and which don't have it.

Comment: great, then just pass to an Azure Functions the file name which doesn't contain the md5, and let it to add that information